# Generate Thumbnail from pdf 1st page using Imagick PHP

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I am trying to convert my pdf file first page to thumbnail and I already installed **ImageMagick** and **GhostScript** for this purpose. **Imagick** extension successfully installed and showed up in phpinfo(). But I am getting the below error:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
$image = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/convert-pdf/file.pdf[0]');

$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
```

Comment: Duplicate the error message as text to make able to find it by text

Comment: I wonder if you have warnings turned off in your PHP environment - you should be seeing a no-such-variable message as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$image` and are using `$im`; try changing `$image` to `$im`.